# Problem with Fedora 14 after ATI Catalyst 10.11 Install

Tags: fedora, grub, boot, graphics

I followed the steps as given in this [article](http://shnwmchk.blogspot.com/2010/12/fedora-14-ati-catalyst-1011-install.html).

After following all of the steps, ATI Catalyst was installed but when i boot my system, I get these options at GRUB:

```
GNU GRUB version 0.97
--------------------------------------
fedora(2.6.35.10-74.fc14.i686)
fedora(2.6.35.6-45.fc14.i686)

other
--------------------------------------
fedora(2.6.35.10-74.fc14.i686) # This is for fedora 14,
fedora(2.6.35.6-45.fc14.i686)  # It now appears on GRUB. This was after the installation of ATI Catalyst.
```

1. By choosing the second one, a lot of commands appear on screen and after that the screen goes blank but the system keeps running
2. Whenever I start up my system, fedora boots a little late
3. The command line interface for fedora appears in very large font
4. Even the graphics appear poor

System information:

- Fedora Release 14(laughlin)
- Kernel linux 2.6.35.10-74.fc14.i686
- Gnome 2.32.0
- ATI mobility radeon HD 4500
- Video Processor ATI Radeon Graphics Processor (0x9553)
- Driver Version 8.553.2.0

Is there any way to correct such behavior?
If not, please tell how to remove the ATI Catalyst.

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

You usually want to install Catalyst from the RPMFusion.org repository.  It does a better job of keeping the kernel module updated anytime your kernel gets updated. But the installer from amd.com should work for the time being.

1. The second option is an older kernel.  When you installed Catalyst it only built a module for the kernel you were running at the time of install which would have been the first option.  If your kernel doesn't have the Catalyst module, you get no graphics at all.
2. I'm not sure what you mean by late?  Do you mean it takes longer to boot?
3. Yes, the console font should be larger.  Before you installed Catalyst you were using the open source Radeon drivers which implements something called KMS (Kernel Mode Setting) which gives you a high resolution console.  Since KMS is fairly new and heavily reliant on the kernel and a lot of open source technologies, the closed source Catalyst driver doesn't use it.  Maybe it will when that stuff gets more stable.
4. Not sure what you mean by the graphics being poor.  Did you set the resolution of your monitor to be the max it can support?  If you're running at 800x600 then yeah it would look poor.

Comment: It takes longer to boot.. the screen resoultion is 1366X768

Comment: the 3-d effects were there even before the installation of ATi Catalyst . 
now Dragging of windows slow/laggy .... how do i uninstall the ati Catalyst 
please somebody HELP